# Issue with api request from linux

Tags: debian, iis, vpn, apache2, curl

I have issue with http bearer auth json post to api.

#### Used apps or and php methods

- wget
- console curl
- php curl
- file get contents

#### Sucessfull scenarios - post request

1. Computer connected to same network as server.

- request from wsl1 Debian
- request from xammp php curl
- request with empty json payload or payload only with id from:

  - virtual box Debian
  - wsl2 Debian
  - server
- request with form encoded payload from all typem of connections

2. Computer connected to vpn

- request from xammp php curl
- request from virtual box Debian with vpn connection
- request from wsl1 and wsl2 Debian

#### Sucessfull scenarios - get request

All typem of connections

**Fail scenarios**

1. Computer connected to same network as server

- request from server with complete payload
- request from virtual box Debian with full payload
- request from wsl2 Debian with full payload

**Fail symptoms**

Sucessfull handshake and http post request. Response from server about window scalling. Eny response after first ack tcp request from server. Few retransmissions and api close connection

**Api configuration**

- iis 8.5
- ASP.net
- http 1.1
- auth bearer
- encoding chunked

**Client configuration**

- windows, Apache, php 7.0 - all types of connections work
- Debian 9, curl - connections work only from a other network or by vpn

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**

I have made some screenshots from wireshark. All machines are in same netwrok as tested server - not api.

[image: Successfull]

[image: Fail]

**Edit 2**

I have done some research and i discovered that it does not work also from other hosting provider. FreeBSD os and console curl. Maybe that information will be helpfull.

Comment: A few things you might consider, 1) Never post everything in a single paragraph. 2) Draw diagrams and build tables when you attempt to tell complex setup and compare failed/successful scenarios.

Comment: I have changed question structure. Do you have and idea how to solve that issue?

Comment: Can you find anything weird in %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR about those failed requests? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/error-logging-http-apis

Comment: I do not have Access to api server  but provider said that logs look fine

Comment: If you don't have access to the server itself, then I think that's impossible to move on. To troubleshoot TCP reset, it is common to use tools like Wireshark on both the browser/server side to capture network packets and identify where the reset packets come from (the server or some network device in between). You can see how important server access is.

Comment: I have done  some  research and i discovered that it does not work also from other hosting provider. FreeBSD os and console curl. Maybe  that information will be helpfull.